# UI routes not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can't seem to get my angular app to work with routes. The basic app itself works but breaks the moment I try to add in routes

Here's a link to the plunker: [broken routes](https://plnkr.co/edit/CMlHDN4vPQnFeDgEANXD?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('appModule', ['ui.router']).config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
    controller: 'homeController'})}])

app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {$scope.hello = "flarg";}])
```

and here is the the same simple app without routes link to plunker here: [working app](https://plnkr.co/edit/BrqxjyuhLwB0dN4h2Pge?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configuration should be like this,

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/home");
  $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: 'homeController'
    });
});
myApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = "flarg";
}]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tgj3E6tmRw35JcAJGxdh?p=preview)**

Comment: thank you, it's always the subtle things that get me with javascrtipt

Comment: Mark as answer if it has helped